# Error with the pandoc beamer template when using bibliography

Tags: pandoc

If this minimal working example saved in `test.md` file:

```
# Part one

## Section One 

### Frame one 

- Items...  [@Publication2001]
```

is compiled with this `literature.bib` file:

```
@article{Publication2001,
  title={Blah},
  author={Blah, B},  
  journal={Numerical Heat Transfer, Part B: Fundamentals},
  volume={66},
  number={6},
  pages={526--543},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

first to `.tex` with

```
pandoc \
    -s \
    -t beamer \
    --natbib \
    --bibliography=literature.bib \
    test.md \
    -o test.tex
```

and then to PDF with the commands:

```
pdflatex test.tex
bibtex test
pdflatex test.tex
```

the following **error** occurs:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Publication2001' on page 3 undefined on input
 line 70.

[3] (./test.bbl
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{1}

?
```

Software versions:

```
pandoc 1.15.0.6
Compiled with texmath 0.8.2.2, highlighting-kate 0.6.


pdflatex --version 
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Compiled with libpng 1.6.18; using libpng 1.6.18
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.36.0
```

Pandoc templates: I am using the current master branch of the [pandoc template repository](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates) for the pandoc templates.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me (I get the same error with the pandoc 1.15.1 on Ubuntu 14.04) , because you can resolve the citation with

```
pandoc -s -s -t beamer --bibliography=foo.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc foo.md -o foo.pdf
```

In order to render your citations correctly, I would search the [Zotero Style Repo](https://www.zotero.org/styles) and add `--csl=foo.csl` (put it into the working directory) to the above command.
BTW, `pandoc` will directly render the beamer slides in PDF.

Comment: This helps, but the bibliography is missing at the end of the presentation. Do you maybe know why?

Comment: You need to put

     `# References #`

at the end of your document. The citations will be placed after this section by `pandoc`.